# Sample code for Windows RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications in the Spooler API?

Tags: windows, notifications, spooler

Windows Vista introduced notifications from the Printer Spooler with the RegisterForPrintAsyncNotifications function  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162919(VS.85).aspx)

Does anyone know of any sample code for spooler notifications using that function?  I have been unable to find any and it seems strange that Microsoft would publish the method without examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows [WDK 8.1](https://github.com/uri247/wdk81/tree/master/Async%20Notification%20Sample) contains a sample VS solution that demonstrates the async API. But it's not part of the Win10 WDK. The solution builds two projects:

- a static library that you can link with your port monitor or printer driver and which broadcasts notifications
- a client app that receives the notifications and pops message boxes or balloon UI from the system tray.

You should probably also check this [MS Japanese article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpwdkblog/2012/02/22/spooler-notification/) which lists the steps required to call the static library api from your existing code.